# Digitally signing document in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, winapi, marshalling, digital-signature

i have a some problem on getting digital signature of the file in silverlight.

I`am using crypt32.dll functions to get signed hash , but i getting confused with unexpected error as a result of CryptSignMessage method - "parametr is incorrect".

Here is my code:

```
  public byte[] SignData(IntPtr certContext, string signingText)
    {
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        Crypt32.CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA param = new Crypt32.CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA();
        Byte[] result = null;
        try
        {
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(signingText);
            IntPtr[] rgpbToBeSigned = new IntPtr[1];
            int[] rgcbToBeSigned = new int[1];
            IntPtr pSignerCert = certContext;
            buffer = Ole32.CoTaskMemAlloc((uint)(Marshal.SizeOf(data[0]) * data.Length));
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, buffer, data.Length);
            rgpbToBeSigned[0] = buffer;
            rgcbToBeSigned[0] = 1;
            int resultlength = 0;

            param.dwMsgEncodingType = Crypt32.Constants.X509_ASN_ENCODING;
            param.pSigningCert = certContext;
            param.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(param);
            param.HashAlgorithm.pszObjId = "1.2.643.2.2.9";
            param.HashAlgorithm.Parameters.cbData = 0;
            param.HashAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData = null;
            param.pvHashAuxInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            param.cMsgCert = 1;


            param.rgpMsgCert = kernel32.GlobalAlloc(0, (UIntPtr)(IntPtr.Size));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(certContext, param.rgpMsgCert, false);
            if (Crypt32.CryptSignMessage(ref param, true, (int)1, rgpbToBeSigned, rgcbToBeSigned, result, ref resultlength) == false)
                throw new DB_Win32Exception(); //throws a string with error message from Getlastresult()

        }
        finally
        {
            if (!(param.rgpMsgCert == IntPtr.Zero))
             kernel32.LocalFree(param.rgpMsgCert);

            if (!(buffer == IntPtr.Zero))
             Ole32.CoTaskMemFree(buffer);
        }
```

Here is my external method declaration:

```
        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptSignMessage(
            ref CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA pSignPara,
            Boolean fDetachedSignature,
            Int32 cToBeSigned,
            IntPtr[] rgpbToBeSigned,
            Int32[] rgcbToBeSigned,
            Byte[] pbSignedBlob,
            ref Int32 pcbSignedBlob
        );

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 100)] //???
            public String pszObjId;                             
            public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Parameters;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA
        {
            public Int32 cbSize;
            public Int32 dwMsgEncodingType;
            public IntPtr pSigningCert;
            public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER HashAlgorithm;
            public IntPtr pvHashAuxInfo;
            public Int32 cMsgCert;
            public IntPtr rgpMsgCert;
            public Int32 cMsgCrl;
            public IntPtr rgpMsgCrl;
            public Int32 cAuthAttr;
            public IntPtr rgAuthAttr;
            public Int32 cUnauthAttr;
            public IntPtr rgUnauthAttr;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int32 dwInnerContentType;
        }
        public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
        {
            public Int32 cbData;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=999)] // ??? 
            public Byte[] pbData;
        }
```

Does anybody knows how i can determine where is the poblem?

Comment: In your example you are using CryptSignMessage, but show extern declaration for CryptEncryptMessage. What is your declaration for CryptSignMessage and other structs which you are using?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I has added requested code.

Comment: 1. Try to change CRYPTOAPI_BLOB.pbData to IntPtr and set it to IntPtr.Zero.
2. Try to change HashAlgorithm to something well know in system, it looks like you are using algorithm which should be installed on system. So maybe it is some security issues, so try "1.3.14.3.2.26" to see if this will help.